# SLR(1) Parser and epsilon involved

Tags: parsing, theory, grammar, compiler-theory, language-theory

Let's suppose I have the following grammar:

```
S → X  
X → a | ϵ
```

If that grammar wouldn't have `ϵ` involved, I would construct the first state like:

```
S' → .S
S → .X
X → .a
```

but what about the `ϵ` symbol? Should I include:

```
X → .ϵ
```

too?

**If so... when creating the next states... should I do `GOTO(Io,ϵ)`, being Io that first state?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `ϵ` is not a terminal itself you have to remove it from your rule which gives you

```
X → .
```

Then later you won't have any strange `GOTO` with "symbol" `ϵ` but instead your state

```
S' → S.
```

is an accepting state in your graph.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have any example of a LR parser applied to a grammar where an epsilon is involved :?

Comment: @Oscar Unfortunately I do not have an example which demonstrates how to proceed. But it should be straightforward to build this by hand based on your grammar.

Comment: I confirmed it in a book I read today ;) It is exactly as you said. Thank you for your response.

Comment: So you mean that epsilon elimination should be applied ?

Answer (score 17):

I agree with Howard. Your state in the DFA should contain the item: `x → .` Here's a DFA I drew for an SLR(1) parser that recognizes a grammar that uses two epsilon productions:[image: SLR(1) DFA]

Comment: I have a problem with this scanned example. Let's have a look at

T(n): T -> .(E) 

goto(T(n), () = { [T->(.E)], [E->.TX], [T->.(E)] , [T->.intY]}
if so, then consequently, for

T(n+1): X->.+E
should I not have:

goto(T(n+1), +) = {[X->+.E], [E->.TX], [T->.(E)] , [T-> .intY]} ?
Instead in the example I have:

goto(T(n+1), +) = {[X->+.E], [E->.TX]}
Why we are not including in goto(T(n+1), +) productions for T?

Comment: You are correct @joanna. While I do not understand what you mean by T(n) and T(n+1), the LR state you are referring to, namely {[X->+.E], [E->.TX]} should include productions for T via prediction. In the current formulation there is no way to progress from the given state since there are no terminals to the right of the dot.